# webdav client with UNC paths on windows server 2012: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, webdav

I'm logged in on a Windows Server 2012 R2 host and I need to access files on webdav servers. One is Sharepoint and the other is Apache. The Desktop Experience feature was installed and the server was rebooted.

I can map both shares as network drives from command line either with `pushd` or `net use`, however , if I try to access the shares via a UNC path it fails. Windows 7 and Windows 10 clients have no such problem.

```
C:\>pushd \\sharepoint.acme.com@SSL\PWA

Z:\>dir
 Volume in drive Z has no label.

 Directory of Z:\
  ...    
              18 File(s)         10 173 bytes
              46 Dir(s)  26 346 717 184 bytes free

Z:\>popd

C:\>dir \\sharepoint.acme.com@SSL\PWA
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this article?
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-webdav/using-the-webdav-redirector

I see you installed the WebDAV director via the desktop experience pack.

However, you haven’t shared how you are mapping the drive, at least I’m not familiar with pushd.

Have you verified the dns name you’re using?  Are you using https?  If so does the cert name match the dns name?

Anyway, the article seems to have a lot of good info.

Comment: `pushd \\unc\path` is a classic way change the CWD to a network place it bat files. It will map a tmp netwok drive, because cmd did not support UNC paths. `popd` will unmap the drive when done. `@SSL` implies `https`. Yes, the DNS is valid. I can open the site in IE.